# No internet connection, wired or wireles

Tags: 12.04

Recently I installed Ubuntu 12.04.1LTS on my Acer Travelmate P253 wich had Windows 8 on it. 
But I cant connect to any form of internet. I read a lot of the same problems and performed al of the replies, but it is still not working. I also cant get another Windows installed. I'm a layman on computers, so thats why I ask you guys for help. 
My ifconfig is:

```
eth0 
link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 20:1a:06:ba:2e:30
UP BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
Interrupt:16

lo 
Link encap:Local Loopback
inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:16436 Metric:1
RX packets:488 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:488 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
RX bytes:39632 (39.6 KB) TX bytes:39632 (39.6 KB) 

rfkill list all

0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: acer-bluetooth: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no

Lshw -c network

Warning: you should run this program as super-user.
*-network
Description: Ethernet interface
Product: netlink BCM57785 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
Vendor: Broadcom Corporation
Physical id: 0
Bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
Logical name: eth0
Version: 10
Serial: 20:1a:06:ba:2e:30
Capicity: 1Gbit/s
Width: 64 bits
Clock: 33MHz
Capabilities: bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bit 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
Configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.121 firmware=sb latency=0 multicast=yes port=twisted pair
Resources: irq:16 memory:90430000-9043ffff memory:90440000-9044ffff memory:90450000-904507ff

*-network UNCLAIMED
Description: Network controller
Product: Atheros communications Inc.
Vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
Physical id: 0
Bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
Version: 01
Width: 64 bits
Clock: 33MHz
Capabilities: bus_master cap_list
Configuration: latency=0
Resources: memory:90500000-9057ffff memory:7ec00000-7ec0ffff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

I am not using my own router

Boot Mode: [Legacy BIOS]
[UEFI] doesn't take Ubuntu..

Network Boot: [enabled]

I hope I gave you the right and enough information to help me out.
I'm looking forward to your reply.

Yours faithfully,

Comment: Are you using your own router?  Assuming you also had your eth0 configured as DHCP client?  The info for these questions will help.

Comment: No, I am not using my own router.

Comment: What should I do then Faron?

Comment: Could you add output of these commands ,too , please: `rfkill list all` and `lshw -c network` ? First command tells us whether the network cards are is blocked (for whatever reason) and second - lists available network cards. I've looked online, you should have a realtek card, RTL8188CE, and realteks in general work well with ubuntu, but if it's broadcom you may need drivers for it